# What is the missing number in the picture

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, pattern

[image: What is the missing number ?]
interesting puzzle from facebook

Answer (score 3):

> 17

because

> 7 + 4 - 9 = 2 
>  13 + 8 - 12 = 9 
>  17 + 13 - 13 = **17**

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 17

Explanation:

> Left vertex + right vertex - top vertex = middle
>  i.e 7+4-9=2, 13+8-12=9

Thus

> 17+13-13=**17**

Answer (score 1):

> 4-2+7=9
>  8-9+13=12
>  13-x+17=13

So,

> x=17

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 17. The pattern is- Add the bottom two terms and subtract the top term from it. 
In first,
7+4-9=2
In second,
13+8-12=9
In third,
17+13-13=17

Comment: Why this downvote?